# Sum vector with number by dinamic intervals without looping

Tags: r

I have dinamic intervals in a Data Frame generated by calculation of percentage of my data, like below:

```
Start   Finish
   0.00    0.86
   0.87    0.89
   0.90    0.98
   0.99    1.00
```

I have a vector with about 3000 numbers that I want to obtain how many numbers I have by each interval without using a Loop because is too much slow.

```
Numbers<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.91,0.99)
```

Expected result in this case: 5,0,2,1....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to go though your start-finish data.frame, check if the numbers are between start and finish values and sum up the logical vector returned from data.tables' `between()` function.

```
Numbers<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.91,0.99)

sf <-
read.table(text = 
"Start   Finish
0.00    0.86
0.87    0.89
0.90    0.98
0.99    1.00",
header = TRUE
)

apply(sf, 1, function(x) {
  sum(data.table::between(Numbers, x[1], x[2]))
})
```

This will return:

```
5 0 2 1
```

Comment: You are most welcome! Don't forget to accept if it works!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dfN <- data.table(Start = Numbers, Finish = Numbers)
setkeyv(df, names(df))
setkeyv(dfN, names(dfN))
foverlaps(df, dfN, which = TRUE, type = "any")[, sum(!is.na(yid)), xid]$V1
#[1] 5 0 2 1
```